# WORD/ VBA: Set a group of radio buttons in a cell via VBA Requirements, row by row

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2016

I want to place radio buttons within a table of a WORD document via VBA. In detail I want to ...

1. Place three radio buttons in column x (3 buttons/cell), row by row .
2. Each button should have no description, only the button itself (size of button symbol only).
3. All three buttons/ cells should belong to one group.
4. The whole thing is to be done in each row (loop).

My problem is that I can create a button/cell, but I am not able to:
a) delete the description text and
b) reduce the width of the radio button (to the size of the button).

I use inlineshapes (ActiveX) to create the radio buttons.
I select the corresponding cell in column X with "Selection.

used OS/ Software: Windows 10, MS WORD 2016

code:

```
Sub add_rBtn()
Dim numberOfColumnsInCurrentTable As Integer
Dim currentTableIndex As Integer
Dim s As InlineShape
Dim c As Integer

On Error GoTo err
currentTableIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count
MsgBox currentTableIndex
'MsgBox ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Columns.Count

For x = 2 To ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Rows.Count
    ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Cell(x, 4).Select
    With Selection
        For y = 1 To 3
            'MsgBox .InlineShapes.Count
            c = 0
            '.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1"
            Set s = .InlineShapes.AddOLEControl("Forms.OptionButton.1")
        Next y
    End With
Next x

Set s = Nothing
Exit Sub
err:
MsgBox err.Number & ": " & err.Description
End Sub
```

Does anyone have a solution suggestion?

Many thanks in advance

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8k6N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like

```
For x = 2 To ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Rows.Count
    ActiveDocument.Tables(currentTableIndex).Cell(x, 4).Select
    With Selection
        For y = 1 To 3
            'MsgBox .InlineShapes.Count
            c = 0
            '.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1"
            Set s = .InlineShapes.AddOLEControl("Forms.OptionButton.1")
            s.Width = 'set an appropriate value here
            s.OLEFormat.Label = ""
        Next y
    End With
Next x
```

This should resolve the size and label issue. You then, however, have 3 radio buttons outside of a frame, so they will behave independently of each other.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem!